# Can't decode timestamp from server after timestampsInSnapshots set to true

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On my node.js server, I have set the recommended `timestampsInSnapshots` to `true` for the firestore database like this:

```
admin.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots : true})
```

In my iOS app I also have timestampsInSnapshots enabled like this:

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.settings = settings
```

From my app I call an end point on my server which returns some snapshot data from firestore. However, on the iOS app I can't seem to decode the timestamps as Firestore `Timestamps` from the objects returned.

Any timestamp recorded in the object are returned in this format:

```
"startTime": {
    "_nanoseconds" = 0;
    "_seconds" = 1535384013;
}
```

whereas before, when I didn't set the `timestampsInSnapshots` setting, they were returned like this:

```
FIRTimestamp: seconds=1535384013 nanoseconds=0>
```

And this was easily decodable to a Firestore `Timestamp`.

When I set the timestamp for `startTime` on my server I use the following:

```
object = {
    startTime: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}
```

How can I fix it so that I can decode the timestamp in to a Firestore `Timestamp` with the new timestampsInSnapshots setting?